# Como fazer uma div ter a dimensão de uma imagem e exibí-la?

Tags: css

Ao declarar uma div e importar uma imagem como `background-image`, é necessário que eu declare o tamanho(`height` e `width`) da div.

Entretanto, digamos que eu tenha uma imagem com o tamanho 900x506(exemplo). E que eu apenas declarei `div` e não atribui nenhum tamanho(`height` e `width`) a ela.

É possível eu importar a imagem via css `background-image: url('minhaimagem.jpg');` e a minha div automaticamente exibí-la, mesmo eu não tendo atribuído nenhum tamanho(`height` e `width`) a ela?

(não sei se ficou muito claro, uma outra explicação..)

Tem como eu declarar uma `div`, importar uma imagem como `background`e a minha `div` "pegar" os valores da minha imagem(`height` e `width`)?

```css
#imagem{
 
 background-image: url('http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/techno_wallpaper_2_0_hd_by_gredius-d5o48do.jpg');
}
```

```html
<div id="imagem">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

infelizmente você não vai conseguir fazer isto apenas com css, vai precisar de javaScript.

```js
var images = document.querySelectorAll(".default-img-size");

[].forEach.call(images, function (imagem, indice) {
  var style = window.getComputedStyle(imagem, null);
  var background = style.getPropertyValue("background-image");
  var inicio = background.indexOf('(') + 1;
  var final = background.lastIndexOf(')');

  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = background.substring(inicio, final);
  img.addEventListener("load", function () {    
    imagem.style.width = img.width + "px";
    imagem.style.height = img.height + "px";
  })
});
```

```css
#imagem{ 
  background-image: url('http://image005.flaticon.com/3/png/512/2/2612.png');
}
```

```html
<div id="imagem" class="default-img-size">

</div>
```

Comment: O snippet não está funcionando /:

Comment: aqui esta normal, qual o navegador que está utilizando? IE8?

Comment: Estou utilizando o Google Chrome, não funciona. Tentei no Edge por questão dúvida e nele funcionou. Em JavaScript existe algum tipo de recurso de compatibilidade de browsers semelhante ao css (webkit e entre outros)?

Comment: @Zkk, estou rodando em uma versão antiga do Chrome (35) e não estou encontrando problemas... em todo caso fiz uma pequena alteração.

Comment: Testei no chrome/firefox e funcionou em ambos.

Answer (score 0):

Há uma maneira bem fácil de se fazer isso. Você precisa saber a largura da imagem e relação de altura. Definir a altura da div para 0 e definir o padding-top como percentagem com base na relação da imagem.

```
#imagem{
    background-image: url('http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/techno_wallpaper_2_0_hd_by_gredius-d5o48do.jpg');
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 56.22%; 
        /* (img-height / img-width) * container-width) */
        /* (506 / 900) * 100 */ 
}

<div id="imagem">

</div>
```

Comment: neste caso você precisa conhecer a dimensão da imagem, basicamente você fez um workaround que sofre do mesmo problema de usar o `width` and o `height` diretamente,